# How to run Jquery on click of a href deep inside divs

Tags: jquery, select

```
<script>
$(".ppg-bronze" ".ppg-signup" a).click(function(){
alert('here');
   $( "#dog" ).toggle();
});
</script>

<div id="dog" style="display:none">Apples</div>
```

I have a hidden div that I want to display when someone click on the A HREF nestled inside of ppg-bronze ppg-signup. How do I set my identifier so they can access that?

It looks like this

```
<div class=ppg-bronze>
<div class=ppg-signup>
<a href>here </a>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I access that A href in Jquery?

Comment: Go learn some basics about JavaScript and CSS selectors. (Just putting multiple strings as arguments for $() is of course nonsense.)

Comment: @Cbroe Thanks for the help there. I appreciate you coming in and giving down votes on this. Multiple strings isn't nonsense. It's called descendant selectors. I haven't worked with those yet. Apparently azeos was kind enough to help me out on that.

Comment: @CBroe I have selected the most helpful answer and then added an answer to help any one else who cruises through looking for help. You should go read about using Descendent Selectors so you can better understand what it means to put multiple arguments inside a Jquery selector.

Comment: I’m fully aware of the descendant selector and how to use it. And you should be able to see that what you have done now is something completely different than in your initial approach – now you are passing _one_ string argument, _containing_ multiple selectors, instead of multiple strings.

Comment: AKA - I attempted to place too many quotes and broke up the selector incorrectly. So while I had the right idea, it didn't warrant you coming into my thread and down voting me and then making snide remarks about going and learning the basics. Unless English isn't your native tongue and you don't understand the meaning of tact. It would seem to me that it would be easier to say "Hey, you used too many quotes. Go look at descendant selectors. You are creating too many strings." Instead of down voting me, taking points from me, and then trying to imply I don't have enough knowledge to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
$(".ppg-bronze .ppg-signup a").click(function(){
alert('here');
   $( "#dog" ).toggle();
});
</script>
```

[Descendant selectors @ W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) and [more](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector).

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just needed to add the word div before the class

Comment: Thanks for your quick and easy to understand help. I also really appreciated the fact you linked me to the W3. That assisted me greatly. I couldn't remember the term Descendant Selector but you were able to quickly jog my memory. I upvoted you.

Comment: The "div" part shouldn't make a difference. May be is because you don't have your classes surrounded by quotes, but I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress you can access divs using Descendant Selectors through code that looks similar to this -

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("div.ppg-bronze div.ppg-signup a").click(function(){
          $( "#dog" ).toggle();
     });
});
</script>
```

You can make a post, add the ready function to the head of the post inside script tags, and then access the descendent selectors using Jquery in order to add an onclick function. This worked for me.